# How can I obtain the DataSource connection through the JNDI name in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am pretty new in Spring and I have the following problem.

I am working on an application, running into JBoss server, that have to perform queries on a DB using **JdbcTemplate**.

Into JBoss I have setted the **JNDI name** that identify the database connection.

I tryied to implement this **JdbcTemplate** simple example and it is pretty clear for me how **JdbcTemplate** works. In this example to create the connection to the database it define a **dataSource** bean and then inject it into the class that use the **JdbcTemplate**, in this way:

```
   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
   <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" 
      class="com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
```

So, as you can see, in this configuration the datasource configuration is explicitly written into the xml configuration file.

How can I obtain it from JBoss through the defined **JNDI name**?

Comment: replace with `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="whater/name/you/use />`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244783/autowire-jndi-resource-in-spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following spring-servlet.xml:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="<JNDI NAME>" />
```

add  following in xsi:schemaLocation attribute of beans tag :

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
```